# Custom HTML/CSS Theme into Wordpress - SEO considerations

Tags: php, css, html, seo

When creating a custom theme that serves all content through HTML/CSS, what is the best way to improve SEO?

I've created a WP theme using HTML/CSS and then adding the relevant PHP to allow WP to serve it. When I open a page to edit in WP, there is nothing there besides the page title.

I haven't added the loop because I don't need it and I don't want to add any content in WP other than using shortcodes and plugins for various additions. This has the effect of meaning SEO plugins don't recognise the site - the sitemap shows there being 0 images, for example.

Other than just putting the SEO in the code myself, is there any way to do it in a better way?

How can I get WP/plugins to recognise the content that exists in the index.php?

Comment: “How can I get WP/plugins to recognise the content that exists in the index.php?” You can’t. You’re using WordPress incorrectly so you’re forgoing compatibility with these things. There isn’t a best practice solution for this situation because it’s not a normal situation when using WordPress. Following best practice would not lead you down this path.

Comment: Welcome to WPSE.  Recommend you start here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask